# Change DISPLAY variable from within Matlab

Tags: matlab, unix

I'm running some code remotely on Matlab on Unix that generates many plots. I don't want hundreds of figures to pop up on my local system. (And I suspect that the windowing process slows down the execution of my code too.) I read that setting the DISPLAY environment variable to null restricts this behavior, and indeed,

```
$export DISPLAY=
$matlab14a -nodisplay -nosplash
>>X=1:10;
>>Y=X.^2;
>>plot(X,Y);
```

Immediately returns the cursor to the console and does not display the plot. However, then I want to be able to toggle the display back on. I can run

```
>>setenv('DISPLAY',':1102') %Previous (correct) value of $DISPLAY
>>getenv('DISPLAY')
ans = 
:1102
>>plot(X,Y);
```

However, the plot still does not appear. I believe that this occurs because my system routes the matlab instance through the qrsh scheduler and then another subshell. So when I change my DISPLAY variable, I believe that whichever shell is not accessing this variable. I don't know the exact details of this process.

My question is, how can I get Matlab to correctly display plots once I have changed the DISPLAY variable to the correct value? Alternately, are there any other solutions for toggling the display of all plots/figures?

Comment: Maybe you could plot the figures with the ('Visible','off') option and switch later to visible on?

Comment: @zinjaai That is definitely a possibility. My hope though was that there was another way to do it because the plotting code is buried deep in my codebase and I wanted to avoid changing it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that running maltab with `-nodisplay` flag makes it ignore completely all figures and I do not think you can recover from that by changing the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

What you can do is setting the **default** `'visible'` property to `'off'`

```
set( 0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'off');
```

Before your code starts to run and only turn `'visible'` to `'on'` for the figures you really want to see. Or, resetting the default value to `'on'` once you are done with the main computation part of your program.

```
set( 0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'on');
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-default-property-values.html) for more info about setting default values for properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the handle to each figure into an array for example. you can then use the command `set(h(index),'visible','on')`